# Why am I getting permission denied when trying to upload to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to add a new repository in Bitbucket. When I type in-

```
     $git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:tylerr82/example.git
```

This pops up-

```
fatal:remote origin already exists.
```

When I type in-

```
git push -u origin --all
```

This pops up-

```
conq: repository down not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I am reading the first error as saying it exists, but when I try to push it is saying it doesn't. When I Google the second error it seems like a connection issue. I only have one public key in Bitbucket and one private key in my pageant. I have deleted all keys and started over with just these two keys. When I type in ssh -T -v gitbucket.org I am getting key_load_public: No such file or directory and at the end of it it says "Permission denied (publickey)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first error says that the remote name `origin` already exists. The second error says that the URL associated with the (existing) `origin` is not valid. The `git remote add` command concerns itself only with adding the given URL under the given name, and does not care whether the URL itself is valid. The `git fetch` and `git push` commands try to *use* the URL and will test it at that time (it may have become valid, or become invalid, well after being added). It's not immediately clear to me what your last (ssh) error means, other than the authentication is failing.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you already have an origin remote

try `git remote -v` to check the url associated to origin it might be wrong

to change the origin remote url try using

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:tylerr82/example.git

git add . -A
git commit -am "first commit"
git push origin master
```

Comment: It is showing the correct origin git@bitbucket,org:tylerr82/example.git in there for fetch and push. If I look at Bitbucket through the gui there is nothing in there.

Comment: On the git commit -am "first commit" it says-

Comment: on branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Then I put in git push origin master and got the same-

Comment: conq: repository down not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.